# Why does this code compile with an unitialized reference?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

How does this code compile?

```
struct B {
    int a;  
};

 
class A
{
  B& b = b;
};

 

int main() {
  A a;
}
```

My understanding was that that reference had to be initialized? It is initialized but to itself? How does this code work and what is the reference of `B` initialized to?

Comment: The `b` is fully defined at the `=`, where the initializer starts. So `b`  can be *used* at that point, but of course not read from until it is fully initialized. This is not much different from `int i = i;`, which has the same problem.

Comment: In C++, there are many syntactically valid constructs which are semantically ill formed, and do not require a diagnostic.  I categorize these kinds of programmer errors as "Doctor, it hurts when I write this bad code."  And the doctor says, "You know it's bad code.  Don't write that bad code."